# How to create vanilla javascript widgets as web components and import into a page dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, web-component, shadow-dom

I am working on a web application which can host mini-apps (or modules) developed in vanilla Js, HTML, CSS.
The host application dynamically loads (using fetch API) the mini-apps (or modules) into its pages and then I want these mini-apps to independently request for their data or do whatever they want to. I want these mini-apps isolated from the host scripts and styling but the host should be able to execute functions of these mini-apps (or modules).

**Example:** The dashboard of Microsoft Azure portal. It has widgets which can be selected, customised and placed by the user, and after loading of the host dashboard these widgets independently fetch for their data. Also, the period and auto-refresh time can be controlled by the host application.

Priorities:
• Modules should be able to execute their own JS scripts.
• If possible then everything should be in vanilla js (or Stenciljs / Vue.js)

```
Current File Structure:

    main.html
    js (dir)
    style (dir)
    
    modules (dir)
    • module-one
       | module.html
       | module.css
       | module.js

    • module-n
       ...
```

I have tried creating custom HTML element and then appending HTML and CSS of module to shadowDom. But I still don't know how to get its JS working. If I insert module.js dynamically to main.html then somehow I need to change roots of all module.js appended in host application from
`document` to `shadowRoot`

Example:

```
//module.js

const sayHelloBtn = document.getElementById('sayHello');
sayHelloBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {console.log('Hello')});


//module.js after appending to host (main.html)

const mod = document.querySelector('module-one').shadowRoot;
const sayHelloBtn = mod.getElementById('sayHello');
sayHelloBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {console.log('Hello')});
```

Please let me know if further elaboration or clarification on question is required. Thank You :)

**Problem Update:**
I get a json of all the modules from an API and dynamically create custom elements with shadow root . I fetch the module files using the fetch API and then append them to the custom elements. I am able to successfully append the .html and .css to respective custom elements but cannot run JS inside shadow DOM. If I dynamically import the JS globally to the main.html then some how I need the JS to access the elements in its shadowRoot and also the functions should not conflict with other module's js functions with same name.

I have tried creating classes in each module.js which holds its respective methods, variable and a init() which does all the module's initialisation.

```
//module.js

class ModuleAbc {
  constructor(host = document) { // shadowRoot is passed when instantiating from the host application
    this.docRoot = host;
    console.log('docRoot set: ', this.docRoot);
  }

  init() {
    console.log('initialising module at host: ', this.docRoot);
    const docRoot = this.docRoot;
    const btn = docRoot.getElementById('cm'); //this element is inside shadowRoot
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('Hello from mod 1!');
    });
  }
}
```

Now I do not know how to call init() of all the classes because their names are different for every module.

```
//HOST JS (main.js)

let mod_name = 'ModuleAbc';
const mod = new mod_name(module_root); //THIS DOESN'T WORK
mod.init();
```

**Problem is resolved using Estus Flask's suggested solution**

Comment: The question isn't specific enough for SO. *If I insert module.js dynamically to main.html then somehow I need to change roots of all module.js appended in host application from document to shadowRoot* - if this is the only problem you see, inject document root as a dependency into a widget. Yes, this means it should have a way to inject things - init function, or selector string as component attribute, or else.

Comment: Use IFRAMEs, not web components

Comment: @EstusFlask I'll try explaining the problem again. I get a json of all the modules from an API and dynamically create custom elements with shadow root . I fetch the module files using the fetch API and then want to append them to the custom elements.
I am able to successfully append the .html and .css to respective custom elements but cannot run JS inside shadow DOM. If I dynamically import the JS globally to the main.html then some how I need the JS to access the elements in its shadowRoot and also the functions should not conflict with other module's js functions with same name.

Comment: @EstusFlask I have updated the problem statement please check it. Thank You :)

Comment: You need to either know classes by names, or make them register themselves on some global and access it then, e.g. `window.myNamespace = window.myNamespace || {}; window.myNamespace.myClass = myClass`. I'd suggest to take a look how AngularJS (1.x) modules and DI work. It registers modules by names which are accessible with `angular.module` globally, and it allows to access module units by names either.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks a lot mate. Got it do using namespaces and method similar to angular JS. I completely forgot that we can store classes too in namespaces just like other objects.